# REINDEX DATABASE concurrently on Azure managed PostgreSQL 11 DB

Tags: postgresql-11

On standalone installation of PostgreSQL 11 I can run command

```
REINDEX DATABASE <name>;
```

and the DB is **responsive**. But when I run the same command on Azure managed PostgreSQL 11 DB, the operation blocks all other queries. The DB becomes irresponsible.

My question is: how can I possible tweak the Azure PostgreSQL DB to enable running REINDEX DATABASE command concurrently?